# Android stream check if noneMatch not work

Tags: java, android

I want to check if none elements from my registration form are not filled (all are filled) but my stream does not seem to work when I fill in all those 3 fields.

Here is what I do:

```
private boolean checkAllFields(ModelRegistration mRegister) {
    return Stream.of(mRegister.getUsername(), mRegister.getPassword(), mRegister.getPassConfirmation()).noneMatch(TextUtils::isEmpty);
}
```

#### ModelRegistration.java

```
public class ModelRegistration {

    private String username, password, passConfirmation, email;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassConfirmation() {
        return passConfirmation;
    }

    public void setPassConfirmation(String passConfirmation) {
        this.passConfirmation = passConfirmation;
    }

    public ModelRegistration() {
    }

    public ModelRegistration(String username, String password, String email, String passConfirmation) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.passConfirmation = passConfirmation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ModelRegistration{" +
                "username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", emailConfirmation='" + passConfirmation + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Why doesn't it work?

Here is another use case:

The class where this `checkAllFields` is located:

#### ViewModelCredentialsRegister.java

```
public class ViewModelCredentialsRegister extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> isPossibleToSendData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<Boolean> getIsPossibleToSendData() {
        if (isPossibleToSendData == null) {
            isPossibleToSendData = new MutableLiveData<>();
            isPossibleToSendData.setValue(false);
        }
        return isPossibleToSendData;
    }

    public void setIsPossibleToSendData(ModelRegistration mRegister) {
        isPossibleToSendData.setValue(checkAllFields(mRegister));
    }

    private boolean checkAllFields(ModelRegistration mRegister) {
        return
                Stream.of(mRegister.getUsername(), mRegister.getPassword(), mRegister.getPassConfirmation()).noneMatch(TextUtils::isEmpty);
    }
}
```

#### FragmentCredentialsRegister.java

```
public class FragmentCredentialsRegister extends Fragment implements TextWatcher {

    private ViewModelCredentialsRegister viewModel;
    private FragmentCredentialsRegisterBinding binding;
    private ModelRegistration modelRegistration = new ModelRegistration();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setToolbarText();

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_credentials_register, container, false);
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelCredentialsRegister.class);
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        viewModel.getIsPossibleToSendData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean aBoolean) {
                binding.bRegistration.setEnabled(aBoolean);
            }
        });

        binding.bRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "yeah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        binding.etUsername.addTextChangedListener(this);
        binding.etPass.addTextChangedListener(this);
        binding.etPass.addTextChangedListener(this);
        binding.etEmail.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        if (binding.etUsername.getText().hashCode() == c.hashCode())
            modelRegistration.setUsername(c.toString());
        if (binding.etPass.getText().hashCode() == c.hashCode())
            modelRegistration.setPassword(c.toString());
        if (binding.etPassConfirmation.getText().hashCode() == c.hashCode())
            modelRegistration.setPassConfirmation(c.toString());
        if (binding.etEmail.getText().hashCode() == c.hashCode())
            modelRegistration.setEmail(c.toString());

        viewModel.setIsPossibleToSendData(modelRegistration);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }


    private void setToolbarText() {
        ActionBar ab = ((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        ab.setSubtitle(getString(R.string.register));
    }
}
```

Comment: In my testing, your code works. What exactly "does not work" for you? What input gives you a different output from what you expected?

Comment: @Der_Reparator hmmm I have added some more code, the problem is that the button (binding.bRegistration) is still disabled even when all this 3 fields are filled in.

Answer (score 0):

I found a mistake. I was setting         binding.etPass.addTextChangedListener(this);
twice instead of setting third field.